# Serving html file in maven-jasmine-plugin

Tags: testing, jasmine

I have a spec in jasmine that tests AngularJS directive. This directive needs html file that it retrieves from the server. So in the code I retrieve it by `XMLHttpRequest` from path `src/main/webapp/partial/components/user-form.html`.

It works when I run `mvn jasmine:bdd` and go to `localhost:8234`. user-form.html is then retrieved from `http://localhost:8234/src/main/webapp/partial/components/user-form.html`.

The problem is when I try to run `mvn jasmine:test`, it fails with error message: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/amorfis/idea-workspace/mc5/mc5-web-ui/target/jasmine/src/main/webapp/partial/components/user-form.html`

Any ideas how can I copy it to `target/jasmine/src..` so that it's accessible in `mvn jasmine:test`?

Comment: It's strange that your plugin wants to do anything in `target`. Normally, only spec runners are placed there. What is your setting for `jsSrcDir`?

Comment: Can't remember the exact setting now, and I can't access the code at the moment, but jsSrcDir definitely doesn't involve target.